# How Can I View Two html pages on live server in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-editor

So I am trying to figure out if there is any way to make a visual studio code live server to display an HTML page I am currently on. What I mean is that when I create an HTML page it displays on the live server but I want to link another HTML page to that page through anchor text but when I go to the new HTML page I am not able to view it on the live server as it still shows the previous HTML page. What I want to do is to be able to have these two pages running so when I click on one on visual studio code it would show that page on live sever and when I click another page and do a bit of editing, save and refresh it should display that new page on live server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on the file and open with live server and then do the same thing for as many HTML files you want to

[image]

Comment: welcome if it worked can you give me a up wote

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the html page and click Open with Live Server or press CTRL+ALT+P

Answer (score 0):

in your tags to navigate to the other pages, include the full url.

For instance http://127.0.0.1:5500/xyz.html

Comment: and you can use target = _blank if you want multiple browser tabs open. All works like standard serving providing you put the full local server path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).