# how to open 2 different files with live server in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, port, liveserver

I have 2 different folders in my vscode workspace containing html..css files
I want to open the two different html files with live server.
when I open the first one it says "Server is Started at port : 5500" and it creates a new browser window and it works, when I try to open the 2nd one it says "Server is already running from different workspace."
how can I solve this ?
I read someone says that I can open it from a different port, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the port of one of your servers.  To do this, go to your `settings.json` file and assign the value `"liveServer.settings.port": 0` to either 0 (for a random port) or another value that is not 5500 so that the servers are running on separate ports.

See this answer for more info:
[Where to set value of liveServer.settings.port in live server extension of visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429643/where-to-set-value-of-liveserver-settings-port-in-live-server-extension-of-visua)

Comment: I changed the value to 0 , the server now is running at a random port but it didn't solve the problem. when I try with the 2nd file it says "Server is already running from different workspace."

Comment: Hm... It looks like you should be able to open multiple files in the same workspace in liveserver by simply right clicking them and clicking ```Open With Live Sever```.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67965138/how-can-i-view-two-html-pages-on-live-server-in-visual-studio-code  Are you sure you're opening both of these in the same workspace?

Comment: It's working only if the 2 html files are in the same folder,  I have 2 folders in my workspace and each html file is in one of them.